# Wrap a function from a JavaScript library for use in my own JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, function

So I am trying to build a JavaScript library.  I do not want to write all my functions from scratch, most of the functions I want to use are already available in other libraries, the point of my library is to group these together into my own library to make things easier for continuous use.

I am looking for an example of how to wrap functions from other JavaScript libraries so I can use them within my own.

The way I had thought it would work was I would reference the libraries in which the functions are being taken for at the top of my code

I would then have

```
function NameOfFunction(){
*wrapped function from referenced library*
}
```

for each function

Comment: Why not simply call the method? f.e. `function NameOfFunction(params){ return functionFromLibrary(params); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `oriented-object` Javascript, that will allow you to wrap functions from other libraries ; still, be conscious that the external librairies need to be there, or you wouldn't be able to use their functions. ;)

Imagine this kind of code :

```
var myObject = {};

myObject.myMethod = function( param1, param2 ) {

};
```

Then you just have to call `myObject.myMethod( param, param )`, 'cause `myObject` will be used  *like* an object. We can easily imagine that you wrap libraries functions inside this kind of method, or even simply return a call to another library function.

Does that answer to your question ?

EDIT : and if you really want an oriented-object style, you can do like this

```
function myObject() {
    this.myMethod = function( param1, param2 ) {
        return externalLib.myMethod();
    }
}

var objInstance = new myObject();
var something = myObject.myMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your library exposes functions in an object, like underscore or any other utility libraries, then you can use _.extend or jquery extend to copy all of them into a single object.

```
var myLib = {};
_.extend(myLib,helperLib1,helperLib2,...)
```